# purpose of ServiceNOW CMDB class

Tags: servicenow, cmdb

I have most basic question about Service NOW CMDB module.
If i have the same type of attributes between 2 different type of devices why I would even bother to create 2 classes instead of 1 with just an attribute indicating the type  of this device?

Is then OK to create the relationship between these 2 CIs within the same class or if i want to create the relations i should actually split these 2 devices into 2 separate classes to indicate clearly that there are different type of devices with specific relationship?

Is there any benefit for creating very detailed classes just to point out that they have different attributes?

e.g. 1. We have a server class, but these days everything is virtualized thus we could use server class to indicate a firewall, load balancer, a switch etc. To just ensure that we can say what it is, we can add "type" attribute to the server class in which you provide: server with OS, router, firewall, switch etc.

e.g. 2. I have a windows 11 laptop running Hyper-V on which i run Windows 11. Should i create cluster or hypervisor class to show dependencies (laptop-->hypervisor-->laptop) or if i do not need info about hypervisor i should just related laptop CI to the laptop CI? Is there any constraint or good practice for doing relationship like this?

Is there any downside of having number of classes? I guess it is just a matter of a life cycle of them that would be a problem, but otherwise any good sides for it?

BR
L